# Logic for login page in netbeans via connectivity of mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to know the logic and how i can implement it in netbeans. I want to create a login option in simple java application in netbeans via connectivity of mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used to do is [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html) for checking whether user status is logged in or not

1. if user is already logged in then I don't lunch the login interface
2. else lunch login interface
3. in log in interface simply take input from user along with primary key (may be email address). and query to database whether it is available in database or not.

If user is available the data of particular user is displayed and preference for user logged in status should changed to logged in.

If user is not available then show some error message.

4. you can add sign up features where you can simply do simple input validation such as age range, email etc and finally insert the data input by the user.

Comment: Actually i m new to java. So i want to know if i can use search syntax of mysql as a logic in netbeans to login or not. If yes then how am i supposed to use it?